# How to update all associated models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, updates

I am using Rails and React. I have two models: `schedule` and `worker`. `worker belongs_to schedule` and `schedule has_many workers`. I want to make an update request to rails from react.

This is what the `fetch` function looks like that I use to send the request:

```
function updateSchedule(scheduleId, date, message, workersArray, cb){
  return fetch(`api/schedules/${scheduleId}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      date: date,
      message: message,
      user_id: 1,
      worker_info: workersArray
    })
  }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then(cb);
}
```

sample of workersArray:

```
[{"id"=>54, "name"=>"Owen
 Johnston", "phone"=>"111-222-3333", "created_at"=>"2017-06-13T22:17:45.769Z", "updated_at"=>"2017-06-13T22:17:45.769Z", "schedule_id"=>33}, {"id"=
>55, "name"=>"Mary Watson", "phone"=>"123-456-7890", "created_at"=>"2017-06-13T22:17:45.778Z", "updated_at"=>"2017-06-13T22:17:45.778Z", "schedule_
id"=>33}]
```

Schedule has date, message, and user_id attributes. Schedule also has a specific group of workers. Each worker has a `name` and `phone`. In short, on a specific schedule, I want to update the schedule's properties, including all the workers name and phone in it. I am having problem iterating through all the workers belonging in that schedule and updating parameters of each worker.

This is the general idea. I am having problem making `update` method to work.

```
  def update
    @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
    if @schedule.update_attributes(schedule_params)
      worker_params["worker_info"].each do |w|
        @worker = Worker.find(w.id)
        @worker.update_attributes!
      end
      render json: @schedule
    else
      render json: @schedule, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

...
  def schedule_params
    params.require(:schedule).permit(:date, :message, :user_id)
  end


  def worker_params
    params.permit(worker_info: [:name, :phone])
  end
```

How can I send a put request from react to rails and tell Rails to update the schedule and all the workers associated to the schedule?

Comment: I don't see anywhere `schedule_params` coming in from the request body..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I see a discrepancy in what you're sending to rails, let's assume that you're sending correct parameters and are able to update schedule (but not workers). The discrepancy is that you're not sending `schedule` key in your params, but requiring it in this line:

```
params.require(:schedule).permit(:date, :message, :user_id)
```

Make sure that your final JSON (which you're sending to rails) is something like this:

```
{
  "schedule": {
    "date": "...your date",
    "message": "...message",
    "user_id": "...user_id"
  }
}
```

Coming to the actual problem, which I believe, is not being able to update workers. Rails has a special directive for models which will ease your pain.

In your `Schedule` model, write:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :workers, allow_destroy: true
```

This will enable the model to update its child attributes as well. Your controller needs to change a bit after this.

```
def schedule_params
  params.require(:schedule).permit(:date, :message, :user_id, workers_attributes: [:id, :name, :phone, :_destroy])
end
```

Then use `@schedule.update_attributes(schedule_params)` to update the schedule, as well as the workers.

Your final JSON should look like:

```
{
  "schedule": {
    "date": "...your date",
    "message": "...message",
    "user_id": "...user_id",
    "workers_attributes": [{
      "id": 123,
      "name: "...name",
      "phone": "...phone"
    }]
  }
}
```

You can pass an array of workers' attributes, which will define if you want to add/update/delete workers related to a schedule. You may want to read more about [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) before proceeding.